# Need help writing Firebase Realtime Database security rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My database is very simple, with only two paths, let's say database/status and database/keys.

I use Firebase Authentication with email and password.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. **anyone** can **read** database/**status** without authentication, but **no one can write**
2. **authenticated users** can **write** in database/**keys**, but they **can't read** unless they have a specific account

How would you write the security rules?

Also, how would you code the following **calls** in Javascript?

1. write in database/keys passing my authorization
2. read in database/keys passing my authorization

I am not dealing with sensitive data, I just want to minimize the risk of losing useful data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's nonsensical. Why would authenticated users not be able to read, when all they have to do is log out and read as unauthenticated users?

Comment: Hey Derek. Did you try to implement the use-case yourself already? If so, please show the [minimal code+rules that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).  If not, I recommend starting in the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) or one of the many tutorials out there.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular maybe you misread. I wrote that users should be able to read status if unauthenticated, not keys. I need keys to be writable by authenticated but readable only by admins

Answer (score 0):

Solved by migrating to Firestore. Granular rules are what I needed.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow list: if request.auth.uid == "useruid";
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == "adminuid";
    }
  }
}
```